# Error on Vagrant Up on Linux

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox

I try to run vagrant on my Ubuntu 14.04. So for, I did these steps:

-Install vagrant
-Install virtualbox
-added box for provider

then I run the

> vagrant up

command.

After running the command, I take these output and at the and there is an error message which I cannot figure out how can I solve and run it correctly.

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>
> ==> default: Checking if box 'udacity/ud381' is up to date...
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>
> ```
> default: Adapter 1: nat
> ```
>
> ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>
> ```
> default: 5000 (guest) => 5000 (host) (adapter 1)
>
> default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
> ```
>
> ==> default: Booting VM... 
>   There was an error while executing
>    `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The
>   command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "0399f946-6a87-4310-a22d-c1a4525ae2f0", "--type",
>   "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine
>   'ud381_default_1463617458900_49294' has terminated unexpectedly during
>   startup with exit code 1 (0x1) VBoxManage: error: Details: code
>   NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface
>   IMachine

What should I do to fix these error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Important pre-amble:**

Please note that I wrote this answer back in 2015/2016 and targeted VirtualBox and Vagrant and Ubuntu headless 14.04.

Your mileage may vary after a while.

If you have a similar problem but for a different version, feel free to edit this answer and append your answer above my answer for Ubuntu 14.04 Let's help everyone to progress together.

I myself will do the same and update this answer for newer versions when I start to use them.

Answers:

## Ubuntu 14.04 Headless with Vagrant and VirtualBox

I found this page when I had the same issue.

Now I have solved mine. I hope that my solution can help you.

### Download the latest AMD64 for virtualbox and install

1. Go https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
2. Choose the AMD64 which is a deb because I am trying to run vagrant on a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 server 64-bit edition (My original problem was that I had used the i386)
3. Then as root, `dpkg -i whatever_is_the_latest_version_virtualbox.deb`
4. `apt-get -f install`  This will install the dependencies

### Download the latest AMD64 for vagrant and install

1. Go https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
2. Choose Debian 64 bit
3. Then as root, `dpkg -i whatever_is_the_latest_version_vagrant.deb`
4. `apt-get -f install`  This will install the dependencies

Then do the rest of your vagrant box setup.

It should work now.

Comment: Thanks @kim-stacks - this actually worked for me. Exact same error as original poster. It seems that my mistake was that I first installed an incorrect .deb package for my headless Ubuntu (used 16.10 where I'm actually running 16.04). Uninstalling both virtualbox and vagrant, then using your instructions got me past the error.

Comment: Same here, Ubuntu 16.04, trying Vagrant 1.8.7 and VirtualBox 5.1 latetest deb. Installing VirtualBox via apt solved the problem (5.0 was installed)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My instructions were mostly for 14.04. It's to Ubuntu's credit that they kept the process relatively similar for their newer versions

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu 16.04 make sure to uninstall any previous versions of virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox
```

The reinstall virtualbox as downloaded from virtualbox.org

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.22-115126-Ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
```

This fixed the error for me.

Comment: Thanks, this and `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` fixed it for me, thanks.

Comment: Doing a simple `sudo apt remove virtualbox` didn't help. I had to purge everything and it worked =)

Answer (score 11):

It has to help:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Then launch your virtual machine.
It helped me ;-)

Comment: This was the command that worked for me.  I tried manually booting the box from the Virtualbox GUI and it specifically said to run this command.  Apparently this error can come up if your installed kernel Virtualbox modules are different than the userspace tools -- such as if you just installed the .deb over the default Ubuntu LTS version (5.0), as I did.

Comment: I had to purge the already installed version and then also `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` - thanks!

Comment: Here, Ubuntu 18.04, bionic, I can confirm that this is working for vagrant-2.1.0 and Virtualbox-5.1.38

Answer (score 4):

I did following steps and it get fixed.

1. Make sure Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. for e.g

http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

https://askubuntu.com/questions/410813/how-to-enable-virtualization-on-booting-ubuntu-13-10

2. Install the virtualbox-5.0 but before you need to uninstall older version of virtualbox. Below link would help:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/install-virtualbox-5-0-ubuntu-15-04-14-04-12-04/

3. Add  v.gui = false at below line in Vagrantfile

   ```
   override.vm.network :private_network, ip: machine_type['ip']
   v.gui = false
   ```
4. Restart the Vagrant:

   ```
   vagrant reload
   ```

Hope it works.

Comment: This worked with VirtualBox 5.0.24_Ubuntur108355 (installed via `apt-get` from default Ubuntu repos) and Vagrant 1.8.7 (installed via `dpkg`) on Ubuntu 16.04 - only steps 3 and 4 were required in my case.

Answer (score 2):

On my ubuntu 14.02 I switch to virtualbox-5.0 worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution :**
`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

**to fix the Error:**

> homestead up 
>   Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
>   ==> homestead-7: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is
>    available! You currently
>   ==> homestead-7: have version '1.0.1'. The latest is version '3.0.0'. Run
>   ==> homestead-7: `vagrant box update` to update.
>   ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>   There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]
>
> Stderr: 0%...
>   Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
>   VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed   to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component   HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
>   VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line   71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS 10.12, reinstalling [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) fixed this for me (Vagrant 2.0.0 and Virtual Box 5.1.28).

Comment: Same for me on Mac OS 10.13. In fact, this happened right after an OS update from 10.13.4 to 10.13.5.

Answer (score 0):

Install all available plugins to container.

1. Get plugin list- Execute

> vagrant plugin list

It will list all the plugins available.

2. Install plugins- execute

> vagrant plugin install

once done issue vagrant up

Comment: I tried but it is not related with the pluging issue because all plugins are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

On my `ubuntu 16.04`, I was using `virtualbox-5.1` with BOSH-LITE same error came while doing

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

I uninstall `virtualbox-5.1` and install `virtualbox-5.0` then it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something new to this discussion, in my experience, this error gets thrown when trying to launch a non-headless VM in non-graphic capable terminal. Wrapper scripts like vagrant and packer tend to go for the simplest options and so by default it seems often their VMs (or boxes) launch a GUI unless it doesn't have one. Fix the graphic terminal problem (say with x11 forwarding) and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the OS on my MAC, things stopped working with the same error as the OP. I upgraded all the other components as well.

I had this environment:
- MacOS Mojave v10.14
- Vagrant 2.0.1
- VirtualBox-5.2.20-125813-OSX.dmg
- VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.20.iso

After that, I did "vagrant box update" to get the latest version 
of the box.

After that I was able to spin **new** VMs.
If you have VMs already created, you may have to deal with Guest Additions version mismatch between Host and Guests.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have virtualization disabled in your bios. To enable virtualisation follow the guide [here](https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968) for different laptop types/makes.

---